# CMake multiple-option setting

Tags: build, cmake, multiple-choice, multiplechoicefield

I'm working on a project which is built with CMake, so I'm writing up a `CMakeLists.txt` for it. In this file I want to have a (cached) CMake variable that can only take one of several options (which I would specify somehow), rather than any arbitrary string. For simplicity, let's take it to be a string which can take "red", "green" or "blue" - but nothing else.

Can I achieve this with a recent CMake version, other than setting an arbitrary string then checking it for validity?

Comment: Can you please give more details about what you are trying to do? Are you delivering a CMake enabled project and want to limit the values of an `option()` possibly selectable in `cmake-gui`? Are you writing a CMake helper/wrapper function and you want to restrict the values of a passed parameter? Are you trying to prevent a `set()` call to a certain variable to get any other then a pre-defined set of values?

Comment: @Florian: See edit. And, yes, I'd like something like a list to appear when I run ccmake (or cmake-gui).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The answer is to be found in one of Kitware's Blog Posts named ["Constraining Values with ComboBoxes in CMake (cmake-gui)"](https://blog.kitware.com/constraining-values-with-comboboxes-in-cmake-cmake-gui/):

> So here’s how it works: for each cache entry that you want to constrain to some set of values, define it as usual with a default value as a `STRING` cache variable, for example:
>
> ```
> set(BaseName "binary" CACHE STRING "BaseName chosen by the user at CMake configure time")
> ```
>
> Now, after defining the cache entry with its initial default value, define the set of strings to which its value should be constrained:
>
> ```
> set_property(CACHE BaseName PROPERTY STRINGS binary octal decimal hexadecimal)
> ```
>
> After the set_property call, cmake-gui knows to present a drop-down combo box for editing the “BaseName” cache entry, and it knows that the four valid choices for this entry that it should present are `binary`, `octal`, `decimal` and `hexadecimal`.

Comment: Is there a way to provide empty string as an option?